# Regex to match capital letters from the end of a string with a twist

Tags: c#, regex, string

Given a string such as "fooBAR", I wish to match the capital letters at the end of the string (i.e. "BAR"), with the following twists:

1. the match must contain at least two letters
2. the match must *not* contain any of the following: 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D

Examples:

```
"fooB" -> ""
"fooBAR" -> "BAR"
"foo64BAR" -> "BAR"
"foo64BR" -> "BR"
"fooDBAR" -> "DBAR"
"foo12BAR" -> "BAR"
"foo1DBAR" -> "BAR"
```

The trivial regex

```
[A-Z][A-Z]+
```

fails the last example (returns "DBAR" instead of "BAR".)

A negative lookbehind such as

```
(?<![1-4D])[A-Z][A-Z]+
```

also fails the last example (returns "AR" instead of "BAR".)

I have a feeling that this should be straightforward, but for the love of me I cannot find the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Just tested and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What should be a match for input `fooBarABC1DB` then? None or `ABC`?

Comment: It should return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
(?!(?<=[1-4])D)[A-Z]{2,}$
```

The primary regex here is `[A-Z]{2,}`, which will match two or more uppercase characters at the end of a string.  The negative lookahead `(?!(?<=[1-4])D)` covers your other requirement.  This can be read as "fail if the previous character was a digit from 1 to 4, and the next character is a D".

If you want to match at the end of a line instead of the end of a string use `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/XgKv9pavJd

Comment: Not sure why you added the ending anchor `$` ?

Comment: The question explicitly states he is looking for matches at the end of the string.

Comment: I just tested this and it only matches the last test "foo1DBAR" -> "BAR"?

Comment: Interesting... as you can see in the Rubular link the regex should be working fine for all of your test cases.  Are you doing all of your test cases in one large string?  If so you will need to drop the `$` from the regex.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be working fine once I drop the $. It could be a difference in the regex engine.

Comment: You should keep the `$` if you want to match at the end of a line. If the input is on multiple lines you need to turn multiline mode on using `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

Comment: I thought that using RegexOptions.RightToLeft would give the same result?

Comment: Not really sure how RightToLeft works with the lookarounds within the regex, sorry.

Comment: Just checked it out and with RightToLeft I think it will always only match the last two uppercase characters.

Answer (score 3):

The negative lookbehind does not work because it requires something other than 1, 2, 3, 4, or D before the match. The "B" in your example fits the assertion, so the match is everything after that.

You need to look for a D that is NOT prefixed by a 1-4 followed by another upper case letter, or any letter except D followed by another upper case letter.

```
((?<![1-4])D|[ABCE-Z])[A-Z]+$
```

Comment: so far this is the only one that works 100% with your added examples

Comment: This also appears to be working with all examples. Apparently I cannot accept multiple answers, so I will go with the earliest one chronologically.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just go with some simple patterns combined with a bit of code, along these lines:

```
string GetMatch(string input)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d?([A-Z]{2,})$");
    if (Regex.Match(match.Value, @"^[1-4]D").Success)
        return match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1);
    else
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex Option `Right To Left` to work from the end:

```
(?<![1-4])D?[A-Z-[D]]{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

F.J.'s regex pattern

```
(?!(?<=[1-4])D)[A-Z]{2,}$
```

is not correct for all possible inputs, such as

```
fooBar1DDBAR
fooBar1DDB
```

A little correction should make a trick:

```
(?<![A-Z])(?!(?<=[1-4])D)[A-Z]{2,}$
```

See a difference at http://rubular.com/r/dGJWj7lE79 (F.J.) versus http://rubular.com/r/mOux7d4zv3